# JavaFX binding mouse click event on Node only works sometimes

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, java-8, mouseevent

**EDIT: Fixed!**

Seems like my issue was with some layers and z-indexes. Maybe someone smarter can clarify. Anyways instead of using the GridPane made in scenebuilder, I attached a new GridPane to scroll pane's anchor pane. Then, I injected the seat images in the fresh gridpane. You can find this on my GitHub.

Bit complicated and specific, but I'll try my best on explaining. Im having problems with binding click listener to ImageView.

My JavaFX app prints graphically randomly generated seats in a cabin in a train. Goal is to save the index of selected seat (by clicking it) in a variable for later purposes. This project is on [my GitHub](https://github.com/tikimo/UTU-Railer) if you want to clone. Below is a picture of the GUI.

Each train has five cabins and you can switch through them, one cabin's seats are printed graphically each at a time. The first cabin to be presented has clickable, functioning seats. Every time cabin changes, this function is called.

**Problem:**

When I change the cabin and new images of seats are re-rendered, I cant click on them anymore. Under here is a snippet of the function:

```
/**
 * This method loads the cabin to the gridpane and also sets the indicator (label)
 * Seat numbering is from up to down, left to right as follows:
 *      1   5   9  ...
 *      2   6   10 ...
 *
 *      3   7   11 ...
 *      4   8   12 ...
 *
 *      and seat index = number - 1
 *
 * @param cabinIndex number of cabinet to present as index
 */
private void loadGraphicalCabin(int cabinIndex) {
    cabinIndexIndicator.setText(cabinIndex+1 + "");
    Cabinet currentCabinet = selectedTrain.getCabinetList().get(cabinIndex);
    currentCabinet.printCabin(); // Prints cabin to terminal
    int currentSeatIndex;

    // Iterate through cabin
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {   // column
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {  // row
            currentSeatIndex = i*4 + j; // keep track of seat index
            Seat currentSeat = currentCabinet.getSeatList().get(currentSeatIndex);
            if (currentSeat.isReserved()) {
                cabinSeatGridpane.add(new ImageView(new Image("FrontEnd/RES/Seats/taken.png")), i, j);
            } else {
                switch (currentSeat.getSeatType().substring(0,1)) {
                    case "a":
                        cabinSeatGridpane.add(new ImageView(new Image("FrontEnd/RES/Seats/allergy.png")), i, j);
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        cabinSeatGridpane.add(new ImageView(new Image("FrontEnd/RES/Seats/disabled.png")), i, j);
                        break;
                    case "e":
                        cabinSeatGridpane.add(new ImageView(new Image("FrontEnd/RES/Seats/economy.png")), i, j);
                        break;
                    case "f":
                        cabinSeatGridpane.add(new ImageView(new Image("FrontEnd/RES/Seats/family.png")), i, j);
                        break;
                    case "p":
                        cabinSeatGridpane.add(new ImageView(new Image("FrontEnd/RES/Seats/pet.png")), i, j);
                        break;
                    case "q":
                        cabinSeatGridpane.add(new ImageView(new Image("FrontEnd/RES/Seats/quiet.png")), i, j);
                        break;
                }

                // Attach click listener to current node
                ImageView node = (ImageView) getNodeByRowColumnIndex(j, i, cabinSeatGridpane);
                System.out.println("we reached seat "+ currentSeatIndex + "  and node is: " + node);
                int finalCurrentSeatIndex = currentSeatIndex;   // Expressions in lambda must be final

                // This lambda is only accessed the first time this method is called.. Why? Or is it..?
                node.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
                    seatSelectorIndex = finalCurrentSeatIndex;
                    System.out.println("Seat " + seatSelectorIndex + " selected!");
                    selectedSeatNumberIndicator.setText((seatSelectorIndex + 1) + "");
                });
            }

        }
    }
    cabinSeatGridpane.addRow(2);
    cabinSeatGridpane.getRowConstraints().get(2).setPrefHeight(50);

}
```

In another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745560/javafx-nodes-not-registering-mouse-events) the problem was having a layer intercepting the clickevent but I dont believe thats my problem.

**NOTE**
I found it interesting that in the debug print line ("We reached seat... " + node) the node (ImageView) is the same as in preverious cabin on every seat! F.ex.:

Cabin 1:

```
we reached seat 0  and node is: ImageView@114e0495[styleClass=image-view]
```

Cabin 2:

```
we reached seat 0  and node is: ImageView@114e0495[styleClass=image-view]
```

**Pics**

Here you can see the settings how you can find a train (run FrontEnd/Portal/portalTester.java)

[image]

And here is the gui when selecting seats!

[image]